# Hybris server startup issue on Mac OS(Hybris 1905 version and Chip: Apple M1 Pro)

Tags: tomcat, sap-commerce-cloud

I am trying to do setup of hybris on MacBook-Pro a nd able to all the things but when I am running below command it failed to start hybris server and trying to find out the license.

Command: ./hybrisserver.sh

output:

```
➜  platform ./hybrisserver.sh 
Running hybrisPlatform on Tomcat...
--> Wrapper Started as Console
Java Service Wrapper Professional Edition 64-bit 3.5.29
  Copyright (C) 1999-2016 Tanuki Software, Ltd. All Rights Reserved.
    http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com

License Error:
A valid license was not found in the Wrapper configuration file.

The Java Service Wrapper requires a License Key to activate the
software.  License Keys can be purchased on the Java Service Wrapper
web site:
  http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/purchase

You can also immediately obtain a one-month Free trial license:
  http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/trial

License Keys can be generated for any of the following HostIds:
  HostId #1 (anpi2):    a6a4824578ea
  HostId #2 (anpi0):    a6a4824578e8
  HostId #3 (anpi1):    a6a4824578e9
  HostId #4 (en4):    a6a4824578c8
  HostId #5 (en5):    a6a4824578c9
  HostId #6 (en6):    a6a4824578ca
  HostId #7 (en1):    36c800323340
  HostId #8 (en2):    36c800323344
  HostId #9 (en3):    36c800323348
  HostId #10 (ap1):    f6d488735235
```

Comment: Which hybris version? Which series of mac, M1?

Comment: Hybris 1905 version and Chip: Apple M1 Pro

Comment: Normally, on local environments, initialize ( "ant initialize" ) solves the issue but be aware that this deletes the entire data from the database and re-creates it based on the impexes that the project has. Also another option would be using a development licence which lets you use the system more than 30 days.

Comment: can't do initialize as I did export of database to avoid initialize.
why it's asking about license.

Comment: Which java version?

Comment: Java 11 I am using

Comment: is your license file still there for the wrapper? `hybris/bin/platform/resources/tanukiwrapper/conf/hybris-wrapper-license.conf´ If not, copy over your platform folder from a fresh project

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the tanuki wrapper and a M1 Mac. Working with Hybris 2011. The way to fix this is to replace the entire tomcat folder in the hybris/bin/platform path with the one from the latest patch release, in my case this was the release 2011.19. Then just run ant all and thats it. They updated the Tanuki Wrapper and inside of the tomcat/bin folder there is now a wrapper-macosx-arm-64 file. In the latest patch release 1905.40 this wrapper was added too, so the chances are good that it works in the same way, without issues.

My hybris 2011 is running with Azul Zulu OpenJdk 11 instead of SapMachine11. The Zulu OpenJdk 11 exists for macOS as an ARM 64-bit build and is running much faster with the M1 MacBook Pro compared to the x64 SapMachine.